# Do I need to use XHTML when I use Apache Tiles?

Tags: java, apache-tiles

Or can I use HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiles are defined in XML, so templates and all documents that have tiles tags need to be in valid, well-formed XML. The documents they produce, however, can be in HTML. So you can define template in XML, and fill it with non-XML non-XHTML markup.